# Pybombs configuration

Tags: gnuradio

I'm a new user to pybombs - there is an error message when I run this command to configure it:

```
 sudo ./pybombs config
```

Error:

```
sudo: ./pybombs: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pybombs installer is a python script its self, you need to call python when you run the installer.

Download and extract `pybombs.zip`

```
wget https://github.com/gnuradio/pybombs/archive/master.zip
unzip ~/pybombs-master.zip
```

Move to the extracted directory and run `setup.py`

```
cd ~/pybombs-master
sudo python setup.py install
```

When you configure you must first change to the directory where `pybomb` is installed

```
cd /usr/local/bin
./pybombs config
```

Tested on 15.10

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this is the answer you are looking for please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to find the right answer, if not, please give feedback.

Comment: Pybombs had been installed , byt when i run this command it gives that there is no command like that as mentioned in my question

The command :
./pybombs config

Answer (score 0):

One of at least three problems:

1. Is `pybombs` actually in your current directory? `ls -l ./pybombs` to be sure.
2. Is `pybombs` executable? `ls -l ./pybombs` to check, `chmod +x ./pybombs` to fix.
3. If `pybombs` is a script, is the script interpreter in the shebang (`"#!`) line installed on your system where the script expects? `head -n 1 ./pybombs` to see it, and unless the line starts with `"#!env "`, `ls -l $( head -n 1 ./pybombs | cut -c3- | awk '{print $1}' )` will see if the interpreter is where the script expects.
4. Other.